# 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken' never called

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ipados

I need some help.

I have absolutely no clue why my notifications are not working.

My AppDelegate looks like this:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print("token: \(token)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("failed to register for remote notifications with with error: \(error)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            print("granted: (\(granted)")
        }
    
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

The problem is, function "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" is never getting called.
I also created "Apple Push Notification service SSL Certificates" in my developer account, added "Push Notifications" to my capabilities in Xcode but it's still not working. Every time I tab on "Allow" to allow notifications, it says "access granted", but it does not print out any device token. "isRegisterForRemoteNotifications" also returns true.

I also searched on the internet for around 2-3 hours, but I couldn't find any solution yet.

I'm using Xcode 12 Beta 2 and iOS 14 Dev Beta 2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to run your code on real device, you cannot get token on simulator

Comment: I did. I installed the app on my real iPhone, but it still not work. If I quit the app in the app switcher, it sometimes says that push notifications are not available on simulators, but it's a real device...

Comment: Did you got string like this `token: ` or what?

Comment: No, nothing. It's like the method is never getting called.

Comment: Can you try change your wi-fi connect to 4g, and open your app again?

Comment: Yeah, that worked. But in 4G only. What's the point of it?

Comment: @pinnokkio, i dont know, but the problem is present with ios 13 and is still not resolved

Comment: Very interesting, how do you know?

Comment: Solve it? I have same problem in iOS 14 Beta 4 now.

Comment: @xyzlast Can you try change your wi-fi connect to 4g, and open your app again?

Comment: I had the same problem. When I run on my real device, it worked. Marshal, I was on Wifi.